# Ubuntu 16.10 - only part of the detail tab is shown

Tags: graphics, 16.10

When I expand the `software updater details` tab it won't show in full size.

My environment:

- Ubuntu 16.10 (x64)
- Intel deo core 2

[image]

Note: even after a restart it stayed the same.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bugs occurring on 16.10, you can see follow-up at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1623856.

AFAIK there are already a fix for this bugs.

Comment: I need further explanations I didn't get it since I'm new to Linux